# How do you search for all incidents of a Canadian airline online?

Tags: incidents, canada

Where can I find records of all *incidents* (per [ICAO's definition](http://www.iprr.org/manuals/Annex13.html)) for a specific Canadian airline, e.g. [WestJet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WestJet)? Typing in 'Westjet' on [TSB Canada's site](http://www.tsb.gc.ca/eng/rapports-reports/aviation/index.asp) produced only 7 results and none this year: this is wrong because per [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=westjet%20boeing%20767%20problems&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=RMkcWPe3CsHo0gSp7aSADw) (and Canadian news sources), WestJet has suffered problems with their Boeing 767-300s in 2016.

Avherald [has more results](http://avherald.com/h?search_term=westjet&opt=0&dosearch=1&search.x=0&search.y=0), but is difficult to read as it does not enable sorting by date: but what are their sources? And shockingly, [Aviation Safety Network](https://aviation-safety.net/database/operator/airline-country.php?id=C) neglects WestJet (the second largest airline in Canada)!

Comment: As far as I'm aware, Avherald used the current sorting settings (the occurrence/update buttons) for the search results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try http://www.tsb.gc.ca/eng/stats/aviation/index-ff.asp on TSB Canada's website. Download the Aviation Occurrence data set and open it in your favourite spreadsheet. It has approximately 60 incidents for WestJet and WestJet Encore.